# mysql how to order by user defined order/sort by number of items on a field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

mysql how to order by user defined order/sort

say for a table

```
---------+----------
name     | category
---------+----------
apple    | 0
orange   | 0
book     | 1
notebook | 1
textboo  | 1
phone    | 2
```

How to order it in the following order of category ie category=1, category=0, category=2
to get the view as

```
---------+----------
name     | category
---------+----------
book     | 1
notebook | 1
textbook | 1
apple    | 0
orange   | 0
phone    | 2
```

How do we write an sql for this?

Also better, if the statement can identify and sort desc based on the number of items on each category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
SELECT Name, Category
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY 
    Case category
        when 1 then 1
        when 0 then 2
        else 3
    end,
    Name
```

**Update**

In the first answer, the order is fixed by category. When ordering by the number of items in category, you want to do this:

```
select name, Category, 
       (select count(*) from MyTable mt2 where mt2.Category = mt1.category) CatCount
from MyTable mt1
order by 3 DESC, name
```

Comment: You can have the sub-query as a table, so it'll only be run once instead for every row found in the table (see my answer for example).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort by the number of entries in the category, you can do:

```
SELECT my_table.name, my_table.category, cats.total FROM
    (SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS total FROM my_table GROUP BY category) cats
    INNER JOIN my_table ON my_table.category = cats.category
    ORDER BY cats.total DESC, my_table.name ASC
```

Comment: +1 because this will self correct as the number of entries in each category changes

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order while writing the query you can use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT name, category
FROM table
WHERE category = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT name, category
FROM table
WHERE category = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT name, category
FROM table
WHERE category = 2
```

Comment: `UNION` does not guarantee order